# Push de um mesmo arquivo com parâmetro diferente no Git

Tags: git, github

No Laravel existe o arquivo **`.env`**.

Nele eu defino minhas conexões de banco de dados, e-mail, entre outras coisas.

Vamos supor que eu tenha 3 conexões:

- Localhost
- Homologação
- Produção

Quando quero trabalhar no localhost eu altero a variável `APP_ENV`. Deixo o valor dessa como `local`.

Quando quero subir os arquivos no repositório de homologação deixo o valor dessa variável como `homo`, e faço `git push origin master`.

Quando quero subir na produção troco o valor para `production` e faço o `push` novamente.

Tudo isso para conexão no arquivo `database.php`. Foi a melhor solução que encontrei.

```
'mysql' => [
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'host'      => (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') ? env('DB_HOST_LOCAL')      : ((env('APP_ENV') == 'homo') ? env('DB_HOST_HOMO')     : env('DB_HOST')),
      'database'  => (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') ? env('DB_DATABASE_LOCAL')  : ((env('APP_ENV') == 'homo') ? env('DB_DATABASE_HOMO') : env('DB_DATABASE')),
      'username'  => (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') ? env('DB_USERNAME_LOCAL')  : ((env('APP_ENV') == 'homo') ? env('DB_USERNAME_HOMO') : env('DB_USERNAME')),
      'password'  => (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') ? env('DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL')  : ((env('APP_ENV') == 'homo') ? env('DB_PASSWORD_HOMO') : env('DB_PASSWORD')),
],
```

Tem como eu automatizar isso via **`git`** ou de outra forma ?

OBS: Criei 2 repositórios no GitHub, um de Homologação e um de Produção para subir o projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Laravel utiliza a biblioteca [DotEnv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) para configurar o ambiente.

O recomendado é ter um arquivo chamado `.env` com os dados de conexão da sua máquina.

Esse arquivo **não deve ser versionado**, pois cada máquina terá o seu.

Todas as variáveis definidas nesse arquivo serão atribuídas às variáveis de ambiente (`$_ENV`) do PHP pelo DotEnv automaticamente.

Por exemplo [este arquivo do Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) seria na tua máquina local:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

...
```

Teu config seria:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
    'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
],
```

E se for no servidor teu arquivo `.env` seria algo do tipo:

```
APP_ENV=producao
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=error
APP_URL=http://meusite.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_producao
DB_USERNAME=usuario_producao
DB_PASSWORD=secret_producao

...
```

E pronto!

Não é necessário alterar teus arquivos de configuração, pois graças ao DotEnv todas suas configuração são carregadas nas variáveis de ambiente.

Dessa maneira o único arquivo que muda de ambiente para ambiente são teus arquivos `.env`. Basta que você acesse seu servidor e crie o arquivo com as configurações corretas.

---

**EDIT**: O autor do DotEnv:

> phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should not be used in production. In production, the actual environment variables should be set so that there is no overhead of loading the .env file on each request

Ou seja, não é preciso nem aconselhável ter um arquivo `.env` em servidores de produção.

A solução é editar o teu arquivo `~/.bashrc` e definir lá tuas variáveis, assim o DotEnv não faz nada e tua aplicação tem todas as configurações de serviços em um lugar seguro sem atrapalhar teu processo de deploy.

Comment: Você falou o que eu já sabia. Porém, quando eu dou `push` ele substitui no repositório, independente de qual seja. Por isso fiz o que fiz.

Comment: O teu repositório também é o site que tá rodando o sistema? Se for o caso teria que usar `git_hooks` para manter o arquivo de config no mesmo lugar, ou então colocar teu arquivo `.env` em outro lugar e fazer o Laravel carregar de lá

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Agora sim. Sim, meu site está rodando com os arquivos do repositório. Faço `deploy`. Vou ver isso aí do `bash_profile` e ver o que posso fazer. Não sei usar `git_hooks`.

Comment: Aqui no meu servidor não tem esse arquivo. Tem que criar ? E como o Laravel pegaria as variáveis dele ? Esse arquivo é criado dentro do projeto ?

Comment: Eu nunca usei `git_hooks` também... mas essa solução do `bash_profile` é uma boa porque dá pra usar em outros projetos também

Comment: teu servidor é Unix?

Comment: É um Linux, Ubuntu. Aqui tem um `.bashrc`

Comment: Isso, é o `.bashrc`.

Comment: Só tem que ver se é esse o arquivo que vai ser carregado pelo user do servidor...

Comment: Então, essa é a minha dúvida. Como fazer para nos arquivos do Laravel usar o `.bashrc` ao invés do `.env`. Tem vários arquivos, pode ser que eu nem saiba quais são. Só conheço o `database.php`

Comment: As variáveis de ambiente são do sistema operacional, não do Laravel. O DotEnv seta tuas váriaveis para SO inteiro. Tu poderia entrar no terminal e digitar `export APP_ENV="producao"` que todo o processo iniciado nesse terminal terá acesso a essa informação

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/58828 tu pode editar o `/etc/environment`